# Export-csv in Powershell v3 - output different than PS v2

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

This is a strange one. Whenever I try to export something to csv using export-csv, the only data in the .csv is the length property. Why is that? So for example:

```
$boogers = "string data"
$boogers | export-csv c:\script\boogers.csv -notypeinformation
```

Now the output will look like this:

```
Length
11
```

What gives? Maybe it's just me, but I can't seem to find very good information on this cmdlet out on the google machine yet. The get-help file is, as per Microsoft tradition, less than helpful.

Any advice you guys could give me would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that in Powershell v2, as well.

`Export-Csv` will create CSV columns for each of the public properties of the input object.  And that's exactly what the (very helpful and detailed, IMO) [docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849932.aspx) say.  `System.String` only has 1 public property - `Length`.

Perhaps you wanted a column named `Value` or something similar?  You can do it like this:

```
'boogers' | select *, @{N='Value'; E={$_}} | Export-Csv C:\boogers.csv
```

Comment: Latkin, thanks for your reply. It was not the same in v2. In fact, I upgraded to v3 while working on a script that used this very method of inserting string variables as objects into export-csv and it worked just fine. Try making $dir = dir and exporting it to csv. Next try making $dir = "dir" and doing the same. As soon as you try to pipe a string, it only dumps the length property. This is definitely not how v2 operated.

Comment: Yes it is, I'm afraid.  You can still run PS v2, just invoke powershell.exe -Version 2.  Try it yourself.